# Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method 

Tags: asp.net

I have a public shared function and I'm trying to access the values of a text box and a session variable.

I'm getting the error "Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared
method or shared member initializer without an explicit instance of
the class."

Is there any way I can get to the values in the textboxes or session variables from within the method?

Thanks,

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function savenote() As String
    Dim newnote As New note()
    newnote.callID = txtRef.Text
    newnote.LoggedBy = Session("user_id")
    newnote.Note = txtNote.Text
    newnote.Create()
    Return 1
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reference session by calling the static `HttpContext.Current.Session`.  Typically with web methods you would pass the value from the TextBox in.

MSDN:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/63zsebh3.aspx